# Cannot create new Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to create a Trigger on the Opportunities object but when I go to the subsection, there's no option for me to create a new trigger. I'm on Salesforce Enterprise edition. What can I do to fix this>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you on your Production org? you can not create New classes, triggers, pages  on production org. You need to do that on Sandbox org and deploy your changes to production org.

Comment: You dont forgot, create a test class for your trigger